# (How to) Average columns in Excel to display error bars in chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel

This seems simple to me but can not find the answer on-line.
If I have several columns of data, each column is just one variable with several entries. How can I make a chart from this data where each chart column is the average value of each data column. Then add Std. Dev bars to this?

Thanks everyone and sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: Why not just make a new row for average values and stdev values? `=AVERAGE(cells)`, `=STDEV.S(cells)` or `=STDEV.P(cells)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an explanation how to Add, change, or remove error bars in a chart. If you create a standard 2D, bar, column, line, xy (scatter) or bubble chart you can display these Error Values on them.

Standard Deviation and Standard Error are the types of bars you can add to your chart

[MS Office Support - Add Error Bars to Chart](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-change-or-remove-error-bars-in-a-chart-e6d12c87-8533-4cd6-a3f5-864049a145f0)

---

[image: Example Chart]

**Add error bars**

1. On 2-D area, bar, column, line, xy (scatter), or bubble chart, do one of the following:

   - To add error bars to all data series in the chart, click the chart area.
   - To add error bars to a selected data point or data series, click the data point or data series that you want, or do the following to select it from a list of chart elements:
   - Click anywhere in the chart.

     This displays the Chart Tools, adding the Design, Layout, and Format tabs.
   - On the Format tab, in the Current Selection group, click the arrow next to the Chart Elements box, and then click the chart element that you want.
2. On the Layout tab, in the Analysis group, click Error Bars.
3. Do one of the following:

   - Click a predefined error bar option, such as Error Bars with Standard Error, Error Bars with Percentage, or Error Bars with Standard Deviation.
   - Click More Error Bar Options, and then under Vertical Error Bars or Horizontal Error Bars, click the display and error amount options that you want to use.

NOTE  The direction of the error bars depends on the chart type of your chart. For scatter charts, both horizontal and vertical error bars are displayed by default. You can remove either of these error bars by selecting them, and then pressing DELETE.